# Return a list of widgets in Flutter

Tags: flutter

```
Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ...myObject
                      .map((data) => Text("Text 1"), Text("Text 2")),
                ]
);
```

This block of code will fail because I'm returning 2 widgets instead of one. How could I fix it and return as many widget as I want without creating another column inside the map?

Comment: Have you tried converting it to list using .toList

Comment: I just tried but I didn't work. How do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you cant use an arrow function to return multiple values, you need to change it to a normal function that returns a list of widgets. Second, you need to use the .toList() method since .map is lazy and you need to iterate in order to map execute.

With this 2 steps you are going to end with a `List<List<Widget>>` and you should flat it before return it to a column that needs a `List<Widget>`. This can be achieved with the Iterable.expand() with an identity function.

You can try something like this:

```
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ..._generateChildrens(myObjects),
                  ],
                ),
```

And the actual implementation to obtain the widgets is:

```
  List<Widget> _generateChildrens(List myObjects) {
    var list = myObjects.map<List<Widget>>(
      (data) {
        var widgetList = <Widget>[];
        widgetList.add(Text("Text 1"));
        widgetList.add(Text("Text 2"));
        return widgetList;
      },
    ).toList();
    var flat = list.expand((i) => i).toList();
    return flat;
  }
```

Hope it helps!